# Where should I store cache of a custom CLI npm module?

Tags: node.js, caching, npm

I am developing an npm module, where user can interact with it through a terminal by executing commands:

```
> mymodule init
> mymodule do stuff
```

When executing certain commands user is being asked for some data, which will be used by the module. Since this data won't really change while using the module and since these commands can be executed pretty frequently, it is not the best option to ask user for the data any time he runs a command. So I've decided to cache this data, and as soon as it should live through multiple module calls, the easiest way to store it that I see is a file (the data structure allows to store it in a simple JSON). But I am to quite sure where should this file go on a user's machine.

**Where in the file system should I store a cache in a form of a file or multiple files for a custom npm module, considering that the module itself can be installed globally, on multiple operation systems and can be used in multiple projects at the same time?**

I was thinking about storing it in a module's folder, but it might be tricky in case of global installation + multi-project use. The second idea was to store it in OS specific tmp storage, but I am not quite sure about it too. I am also wondering if there are some alternatives to file storage in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On some systems you can cache to `~/.cache` by create a sub-directory to store your cache data, though its much more common for applications to create a hidden directory in the users home directory. On modern windows machines you can use create a directory in `C:/Users/someUser/AppData`. In Windows using a `.` suffix will not hide a file. I'd recommend you do something platform agnostic like so:

```
var path = require('path');

function getAppDir(appName, cb) {
    var plat = process.platform;

    var homeDir = process.env[(plat == 'win32') ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'];
    var appDir;

    if(plat == 'win32') {
        appDir = path.join(homeDir, 'AppData', appName);
    }
    else {
        appDir = path.join(homeDir, '.' + appName);
    }

    fs.mkdir(appDir, function(err) {
        if(err) return cb(err);

        cb(null, appDir);
    })
}
```

Just declare a function to get the app directory. This should handle most systems, but if you run into a case where it does not it should be easy to fix because you can just create some kind of alternate logic here. Lets say you want to allow a user to specify a custom location for app data in a config file later on, you could easily add that logic. For now this should suite most of your cases for most all Unix/Linux systems and Windows Vista and up.

Storing in system temp folder, depending on the system, your cache could be lost on an interval(cron) or on reboot. Using the global install path would lead to some issues. If you need this data to be unique per project, then you can extend that functionality to allow you to store this data in the project root, but not the module root. It would be best not to store it in the module root, even if its just installed as a local/project module, because then the user doesn't have the ability to include this folder in their repositories without including the entire module.

So in the event that you need to store this cached data relevant to a project, then you should do so in the project root not the `node_modules`. Otherwise store it in the users home directory in a system agnostic way.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Now I get that a system tmp folder is a bad idea. Regarding the question about data per project: yes, it's a good approach to store module config file and other info which is unique for project in it's root, but in my case I want to make configuration cross-project, so a user could use one configuration for multiple projects or even without any project. I think it's a separate issue to think about, but OS home folder definitely suites well for this case.

Comment: Right, I felt is was worth mentioning the best practice for storing per-project related data. If you're not concerned about that then just store it in the users home folder. Doing it as depicted above will make it system agnostic.

Answer (score 7):

I would create a hidden folder in the user's home directory (starting with a dot). For instance, `/home/user/.mymodule/config.cfg`. The user's home directory isn't going anywhere, and the dot will make sure it's out of the user's way unless they go looking for it.

This is the standard way that most software stores user configs, including SSH, Bash, Nano, Wine, Ruby, Gimp, and even NPM itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to be a good solution and there is a way to work with these home folders across the OS. But one thing that I've stumbled upon recently, which did not had place in the original question, that node.js and npm can be installed in multiple namespaces on the same machine using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), which is widely used by developers nowadays. And because of that I am not sure how to adopt this one global home folder storage for possible multiple installations of npm with separate global namespaces and my module within all of them respectively.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov From within your module, check the variable `process.version` to get the version of NodeJS that your script is being run under. Then you can create a separate folder for each Node version. For instance for NodeJS v0.10.25 you would have `/home/user/.mymodule/0.10.25/config.cfg`, for v0.6.8 you would have `/home/user/.mymodule/0.6.8/config.cfg`, etc.

Comment: Sounds great, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov Did my solution ever end up working for you?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not have time to try it yet, but your addition about using `process.version` is really helpful and I'll definitely use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First you need to know in what kind of SO you are running:

1. Your original idea is not bad, because global modules are not really global in all SO and in all virtual enviroments.
2. Using /home/user may not work in Windows. In windows you have to check process.ENV.HOMEPAHT

I recommend you a chain of checks to determine the best place.

1. Let the user take the control. Chose your own env variable. Supouse MYMOD_HOME. You firts check if `process.ENV.MYMOD_HOME` exists, and use it
2. Check if windows standard `process.ENV.LOCALAPPDATA`
3. Check if windows standard `process.ENV.HOMEPATH`
4. Check if exists `'/home/user'` or `'~'`
5. Otherwise use `__dirname`

In all cases create a directory `./mymodule`

Comment: Thank you. The first step about setting custom path with the help of node.js env variables is a really nice option. In case when I was not able to find a home folder on steps 1-4, is your advice to fallback to module's directory?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the best option in that case. The module directory may be in the user global modules or in the global modules of the virtual enviroment. May be not, but still a good option.